# reanimated-bottom-sheet snapTo function works at second firing

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm using reanimated-bottom-sheet. Trying to close modal with this

```
this.bottomSheetRef.current.snapTo(0)
```

but this works at second click. If there is 3 snapPoint it goes heighest one at first than goes to where I want but at second click

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code to avoid issues with *snapTo(0)*.

Method to close:

```js
closeBottomSheet = () => {
    if (this.bottomSheetRef && this.bottomSheetRef.snapTo) this.bottomSheetRef.snapTo(0);
}
```

Example component:

```js
<BottomSheet
    ref={ref => this.bottomSheetRef= ref}
    snapPoints={[0, 300, 600]}
    initialSnap={0}
/>
```

Comment: this.bottomSheetRef.current.snapTo(0),
this.bottomSheetRef.current.snapTo(0) Had to write like this